# Где хранятся временные таблицы MySQL (TEMPORARY TABLE)?

Tags: mysql, debian

Она создается в папке /tmp сервера? Можно ли определить другой путь создания временной таблицы, чтобы не уничтожалась в папке /tmp? 
Какая скорость запросов с временной таблицы.
Временная таблица содержит миллион строк.

Comment: по поводу местоположения и его изменения достаточно подробно изложено в [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По возможности MySQL пытается разместить временную таблицу в оперативной памяти. Максимальный размер такой таблицы определяется системной переменной `tmp_table_size` значение которой можно установить в конфигурационном файле my.cnf в секции [mysqld] (по умолчанию размер 16Мб). Обратите внимание, что размер определяется именно объемом памяти, а не количеством строк - придется вычислять, влазит таблица или нет. `EXPLAIN`, к сожалению, не сообщает эту информацию - если он утверждает, что будет использоваться файловая сортировка, то она может проходить как в оперативной памяти, так и на диске, в зависимости от того убирается результирующая таблица в `tmp_table_size` или нет.

```
[mysqld]
...
tmp_table_size = 128M
```

Для временных файлов MySQL использует системную папку временных файлов. Однако, ее можно изменить при помощи директивы `tmpdir`, которую также следует разместить в конфигурационном файле my.cnf в секции [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]
...
tmpdir = /path/to/anoter/tmp
tmp_table_size = 128M
```

После перезагрузки, сервер будет использовать новую временную папку.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ,да, был создан `tmpdir`, но, можно спросить про цитату:" EXPLAIN, к сожалению, не сообщает эту информацию - если он утверждает, что будет использоваться файловая сортировка",- это как?

Comment: @NNN Иногда в поле additional EXPLAIN-отчета (получить его можно добавив EXPLAIN перед любым SELECT-запросом) выводится надпись "Using filesort" - это означает, что промежуточная результирующая таблица будет выгружена на жесткий диск и отсортирована на нем, после чего результаты будут отправлены клиенту. Однако, если объем оперативной памяти, выделенной в tmp_table_size позволяет, то вместо жесткого диска эта операция будет произведена в оперативной памяти. Поэтому "Using filesort" не всегда означает операцию на жестком диске.

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!!-)